# How to add controls when an event is fired in WinForm?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i like to add controls inside the form1 where a event handler for
   watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged); is defined , is it possible to add control for example list box to the form1 but need to be added inside the event handler where it is defined

```
  /*event added*/ 

   private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] args = {this.txtfolder.Text};
        if (args.Length != 1)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Invalid Operation");
            return;
        }

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[0];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = this.txtfilter.Text;//"*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        // watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);



   // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        //Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

        //   Form1 F   ;        
       // ListBox lst = new ListBox();
        //lst.Items.Add("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType.ToString());
        //f.lsttracker.Items.Add("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType.ToString());
       // F.controls.Add(lst);
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But it will get added each time the event is raised, which is probably not what you want. Hard to tell what your code is demonstrating. Why is all that stuff commented out?

Comment: Did you try it? (Note: Is it possible questions usually end up being downvoted).

Comment: @selvannand try this sample. I think this does what you are trying to do: dl.dropbox.com/u/18919663/vs%20samples/TestingSandbox.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your looking for. From what you commented out, you probably didn't set the location and size, thus adding the control probably wasn't working. But you should really make sure to regulate this and make sure you are only adding controls exactly when you want to and no more.

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox toAdd = new ListBox();
    toAdd.Location = new Point(20,20);
    toAdd.Size = new Size(200,200);
    this.Controls.Add(toAdd);
}
```

If you want to store the controls you added, try something like this:

```
private List<Control> AddedItems = new List<Controls>();
private int OffsetY = 0;
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox toAdd = new ListBox();
    if(AddedItem.Last().Point.Y == OffsetY) // just an example of reusing previously added items.
    {
         toAdd.Location = new Point(20, OffsetY);
         toAdd.Size = new Size(200,200);
         AddedItems.Add(toAdd);
         this.Controls.Add(toAdd);
    }
    OffsetY += 200;
}
```

EDIT: In reply to what you mentioned in the comment below.

```
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FolderPath = this.txtfolder.Text;
        string Filter = this.txtfilter.Text;
        if(!Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid directory"); //checks directory is valid
            return;
        }

        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        watcher.Path = FolderPath;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch filter files.
        watcher.Filter = Filter;

        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true; //monitor subdirectories?
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; //allows for changed events to be fired.

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    }
    //Delegate to get back to UI thread since OnChanged fires on non-UI thread.
    private delegate void updateListbox(string context);
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new updateListbox(UpdateListbox), "File: " + e.Name);
        this.Invoke(new updateListbox(UpdateListbox), ">>Action: " + e.ChangeType);
        this.Invoke(new updateListbox(UpdateListbox), ">>Path: " + e.FullPath);
    }
    public void UpdateListbox(string context)
    {
        lsttracker.Items.Add(context);
    }
```

Comment: HI,thanks for the explanation but actually i need to add the values to listbox named lsttracker to the form1 , when the event handler fires it will do the following stuffs as given below

Comment: HI,thanks for the explanation but actually i need to add the values to listbox named lsttracker to the form1 , when the event handler fires it will do the following stuffs as given below   private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
             File.Delete(e.FullPath);  //after this i need to add values or the path of the file deleted to the listbox named lsttracker    of the  form1                       
         }//this is what i required ,please help me if anybody knows

Comment: Check out my edit. I think that is what you are looking for. :]

You might have been having issues since you had your OnChange event handler as static, which wont let you reference non-static form elements.

Comment: Based on your code, I see quite a few issues in the code. I recreated what your doing in my own project, hopefully this helps:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18919663/vs%20samples/TestingSandbox.zip

Comment: @selvaanand Basically, you need to set watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; to monitor the events. But the events come in on a different thread, so you need to do a delegate invoke to get the results back to the UI thread. Check out my sample. If you don't have visual studio 2008, just look at the Form1.cs file.

Comment: Thanks all and especially to corylulu...i got it

Comment: Dont forget to select Best Answer :P